# What's the correct form of the word "esoterics", it being a subject?

Tags: nouns

What noun would one use to define the whole area of esoteric related matters? In some dictionaries, it is "Esoteric" or "Esotericism", in others - "Esoterics" or "Esoterica". Which of them are the most appropriate?

For example, an "Esoterics and Parapsycology Training Centre" (a centre where they study such subjects as parapsychology and esoterics). Which that be correct: esoteric or esoterics?

Or "a diploma in Esoterica".

How should the correct version sound?

Comment: How would you _train_ anyone in that stuff?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That would be a secret.